# Allocate memory for char array pointer of struct inside function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I was looking around for about one day on how to solve my problem. I find solutions for problems similar to mine but when I apply changes error : `error: request for member 'mark' in something not a structure or union` keeps showing.

What I have so far is a `struct` and I want to initialize it on a function call.

**Edit my code:**

```
typedef struct student * Student;

struct student {
    char *mark; /* or array[2] like array[0] = 'A' , array[1] = 'B' */
    int age;
    int weight;
};

typedef enum{
    MEMORY_GOOD,
    MEMORY_BAD} Status; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int status = 0; 

    Student john  


    /* Function  call to allocate memory*/

    status = initMemory(&john);

    return(0);
}


Status initMemory(Student *_st){
     _st =  malloc(sizeof(Student));


    printf("Storage size for student : %d \n", sizeof(_st));

    if(_st == NULL)
    {
        return MEMORY_BAD;
    }   

    _st->mark = malloc(2*sizeof(char)); /* error: request for member 'mark' in something not a structure or union */

    return MEMORY_GOOD; 
}
```

Comment: Postfix `->` has higher precedence than unary `*`.

Comment: This code is full of syntax errors. Also, `john` is not a pointer to a struct.

Comment: @EOF Even adding parens wouldn't help. `_st` is a triple pointer; `*` and `->` only dereference twice.

Comment: @melpomene Ah, the old `typedef`d pointer. A classic.

Comment: Can you point them(full of errors) to me, like that, I can fix them.

Comment: @DavidEdgar I'd recommend turning on compiler warnings. Compilers know C very well, they can tell you a lot about it.

Comment: @DavidEdgar Just try to compile your code. Your compiler should point out all syntax errors.

Comment: So my problem is not only in this line : *_st->mark = malloc(2*sizeof(char));

Comment: Your first problem is `Student *john status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
_st->mark = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
```

With

```
(*_st)->mark = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
```

**_st** is a pointer wich **content** is the address of the struct, so ...

1) first you need to **dereference** *_st*, and... 
2) second, with the **value** you get, you point to the field *mark*

That's all !

Answer (score 1):

try to avoid too many *s in your code,

was able to run it after making some changes, please refer to the ideone link in the next line.

http://ideone.com/Ow2D2m

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct student* Student; // taking Student as pointer to Struct
int initMemory(Student );
struct student {
char* mark; /* or array[2] like array[0] = 'A' , array[1] = 'B' */
int age;
int weight;
};

typedef enum{
    MEMORY_GOOD,
    MEMORY_BAD} Status; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Status status;

    Student john;  /* Pointer to struct */

  /* Function  call to allocate memory*/
    status = initMemory(john);
    printf("got status code %d",status);
}

int initMemory(Student _st){
     _st =  (Student)malloc(sizeof(Student));

    printf("Storage size for student : %d \n", sizeof(_st));
    if(_st == NULL)
    {
        return MEMORY_BAD;
    }   else {
        char* _tmp = malloc(2*sizeof(char)); /* error: request for member     'mark' in something not a structure or union */
    _st->mark = _tmp;
    return MEMORY_GOOD; 
    }
 }
```